# Temporary ASP.NET Files keeps growing

Tags: windows-server-2008, iis-7

Seems that the assemblies from my web apps are eating all my precious server disk space. Why is that and how do I clean this up?

```
   227.778  c:\windows\microsoft.net\framework64\v2.0.50727\temporary asp.net files\integrator
   331.373  c:\windows\microsoft.net\framework64\v2.0.50727\temporary asp.net files\root
 4.881.531  c:\windows\microsoft.net\framework64\v2.0.50727\temporary asp.net files\services
   139.975  c:\windows\microsoft.net\framework64\v2.0.50727\temporary asp.net files\test
 1.411.048  c:\windows\microsoft.net\framework64\v2.0.50727\temporary asp.net files\test_services
 1.917.421  c:\windows\microsoft.net\framework64\v2.0.50727\temporary asp.net files\web
 8.909.129  c:\windows\microsoft.net\framework64\v2.0.50727\temporary asp.net files

Files:        23953
Directories:  19487
Size:         9.122.948.617 bytes
Size on disk: 9.122.948.617 bytes
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can have a look inside these folders to see, what files are big. For the cleanup part. You can safely delete these files using Windows Explorer. The best would be to stop IIS for this operation and start it afterwards again (if possible). The necessary files will be regenerated.

But you should definitely try to find out WHY stuff grows that much

Comment: OK, I understand now. The reason it grows is that we're doing continous integration, sometimes deploying several times a day. Stopping IIS is not an option, but I guess I can just manually delete the oldest folders and be safe.

Comment: Yes you can also delete the files when IIS is running (except the currently locked files of course)

Answer (score 0):

You can also move these files to another drive so that they can grow as needed.  It's set in your root machine.config file in your framework/config folder.  Search for tempDirectory=....